# FlatFileItemReader using FixedLengthTokenizer not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I m doing an example in SpringBatch using   a FlatFileItemReader with  FixedLengthTokenizer to read from text file and save to an xml file. I got an error :Bean property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter? (I will put the hole  console log). thank you for any help .
config file : spring-batch-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource1"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
           <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"></property>
           <property name="url" value="********"></property>
           <property name="password" value="*****"></property>
           <property name="username" value="******"></property>
         </bean>  
         <bean id="dataSource2"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
           <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"></property>
           <property name="url" value="*******"></property>
           <property name="password" value="*****"></property>
           <property name="username" value="*****"></property>
         </bean>

     <bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"  scope="step">

        <property name="resource" value="txt/flatfile" />
        <property name="lineMapper">

            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                     <bean class="artifact1.StudentFieldSetMapper" />
                   </property>
                <property name="fixedLengthTokenizer">
                   <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                      <property name="names" value="fisrtName,id, phone,lastName ,streetName,age,city, date_of_birth,quantity,sin ,code"></property>
                      <property name="columns" value="1-4,6-9,10-13,15-18,19-22,23-26,27-31,33-40,45-47,48-53,55-55"></property>
                   </bean>
                </property> 
           </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


 <bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">

        <property name="resource" value="file:xml/etudiant.xml" />

        <property name="rootTagName" value="Student" />

        <property name="marshaller">

            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                <property name="classesToBeBound">
                    <list>
                        <value>artifact1.ExamResult</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>

        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <batch:job id="examResultJob">
        <batch:step id="step105" >
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="flatFileItemReader" writer="xmlItemWriter"   commit-interval="2" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

    </batch:job>
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"> 
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"></property>
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
   <property name="databaseType" value="oracle"></property>
 </bean > 

 <bean  id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
   <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"> </property>
 </bean>

 </beans>
```

main.java :

```
package artifact1;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main1 
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    ApplicationContext context=new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/batch/spring-batch-context.xml");
    JobLauncher jobLuncher= (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job=(Job) context.getBean("examResultJob");

    try
    {

      JobExecution jobExecution=jobLuncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
      System.out.println("job completed  :"+jobExecution.getStatus());
    }
    catch (JobExecutionException e)
    {
      System.out.println("job failed :");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Student.java POJO :

```
package artifact1;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="etud")
public class Student
{
  String fisrtName;
  Integer id;
  Integer phone;
  String lastName;
  String streetName;
  Integer age;
  String city;
  String date_of_birth;
  Integer quantity;
  Integer sin;
  Short code;
  @XmlElement(name= "prenom")
  public String getFisrtName()
  {
    return fisrtName;
  }
  public void setFisrtName(String fisrtName)
  {
    this.fisrtName = fisrtName;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "idd")
  public Integer getId()
  {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Integer id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "tel")
  public Integer getPhone()
  {
    return phone;
  }
  public void setPhone(Integer phone)
  {
    this.phone = phone;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "nom")
  public String getLastName()
  {
    return lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName)
  {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "trig")
  public String getStreetName()
  {
    return streetName;
  }
  public void setStreetName(String streetName)
  {
    this.streetName = streetName;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "age")
  public Integer getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }
  public void setAge(Integer age)
  {
    this.age = age;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "ville")
  public String getCity()
  {
    return city;
  }
  public void setCity(String city)
  {
    this.city = city;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "datenaiss")
  public String getDate_of_birth()
  {
    return date_of_birth;
  }
  public void setDate_of_birth(String date_of_birth)
  {
    this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "quant")
  public Integer getQuantity()
  {
    return quantity;
  }
  public void setQuantity(Integer quantity)
  {
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "sin")
  public Integer getSin()
  {
    return sin;
  }
  public void setSin(Integer sin)
  {
    this.sin = sin;
  }
  @XmlElement(name= "cd")
  public Short getCode()
  {
    return code;
  }
  public void setCode(Short code)
  {
    this.code = code;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "Student [fisrtName=" + fisrtName + ", id=" + id + ", phone=" + phone + ", lastName="
        + lastName + ", streetName=" + streetName + ", age=" + age + ", city=" + city
        + ", date_of_birth=" + date_of_birth + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", sin=" + sin + ", code="
        + code + "]";
  }


}
```

StudentFieldSetMapper:

```
package artifact1;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

public class StudentFieldSetMapper implements  FieldSetMapper<Student>
{

  public Student mapFieldSet(FieldSet fs) throws BindException
  {
    System.out.println("inside StudentFieldSetMapper");
    Student et=new Student();
    et.setFisrtName(fs.readString(0));
    et.setId(fs.readInt(1));
    et.setPhone(fs.readInt(2));
    et.setLastName(fs.readString(3));
    et.setStreetName(fs.readString(4));
    et.setAge(fs.readInt(5));
    et.setCity(fs.readString(6));
    et.setDate_of_birth(fs.readString(7));
    et.setQuantity(fs.readInt(8));
    et.setSin(fs.readInt(9));
    et.setCode(fs.readShort(10));
    return et;
  }

}
```

log console:

```
2018-10-26 13:56:42 ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:229 - Encountered an error executing step ste
p105 in job examResultJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.flatFileItemReader'
 defined in class path resource [spring/batch/spring-batch-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.b
atch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper#184f6be2' of type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMappe
r] while setting bean property 'lineMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper#184f6be2' defined in clas
s path resource [spring/batch/spring-batch-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springfr
amework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' of bean class [org.springframework.b
atch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper]: Bean property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter
 method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.j
ava:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueRes
olver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at artifact1.Main1.main(Main1.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.b
atch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper#184f6be2' defined in class path resource [spring/batch/spring-batch-context.xml
]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid pr
operty 'fixedLengthTokenizer' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper]: Bean proper
ty 'fixedLengthTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match t
he return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.j
ava:299)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' of bean class
 [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper]: Bean property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' is not writable o
r has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.jav
a:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:29
0)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:27
8)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 30 more
2018-10-26 13:56:42 ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:274 - Exception while closing step execution 
resources in step step105 in job examResultJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.flatFileItemReader'
 defined in class path resource [spring/batch/spring-batch-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.b
atch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper#184f6be2' of type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMappe
r] while setting bean property 'lineMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper#184f6be2' defined in clas
s path resource [spring/batch/spring-batch-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springfr
amework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' of bean class [org.springframework.b
atch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper]: Bean property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter
 method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.j
ava:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueRes
olver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:305)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at artifact1.Main1.main(Main1.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.b
atch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper#184f6be2' defined in class path resource [spring/batch/spring-batch-context.xml
]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid pr
operty 'fixedLengthTokenizer' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper]: Bean proper
ty 'fixedLengthTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match t
he return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.j
ava:299)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' of bean class
 [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper]: Bean property 'fixedLengthTokenizer' is not writable o
r has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.jav
a:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:29
0)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:27
8)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 30 more
job completed  :FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the config spring bach file : spring-batch-context.xml :
I changed this  :

```
<property name="fixedLengthTokenizer">
                   <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                      <property name="names" value="fisrtName,id, phone,lastName ,streetName,age,city, date_of_birth,quantity,sin ,code"></property>
                      <property name="columns" value="1-4,6-9,10-13,15-18,19-22,23-26,27-31,33-40,45-47,48-53,55-55"></property>
                   </bean>
                </property>
```

to :

```
<property name="lineTokenizer">
                   <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                      <property name="names" value="fisrtName,id, phone,lastName ,streetName,age,city, date_of_birth,quantity,sin ,code"></property>
                      <property name="columns" value="1-4,6-9,10-13,15-18,19-22,23-26,27-31,33-40,45-47,48-53,55-55"></property>
                   </bean>
                </property>
```

it's worked fine.